# UITableViewCell swipe does not show the delete button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe

I'm currently working on a UITableViewController demo which works just the way I wanted it to work.

The only thing I don't get is the missing delete button, when swiping to the left on a row.

The "space" of the button and also the delete functionality are there, but neither the red rectangle button nor the text "delete" shows up.

This happens in the simulator and also on the device.

Of course, I have implemented "edititingStyleForRowAtIndexPath'

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    switch indexPath.section{
    case SectionConstants.MODEL_DATA_SECTION: return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    case SectionConstants.NEW_DATA_SECTION: return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert
    default: return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
    }
}
```

and 'commitEditingStyle' which is irrelevant for this, as it is triggered after the delete button has been touched.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this behavior or faced a similar issue?

Best regards,
Steffen

[Edit]
Actually, I forgot to add a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1mSS.png) :)

Comment: Make sure your cell content is added to the cell's `contentView` and not the cell itself. Your content might be hiding the Delete button.

Comment: I am having the same problem. If I put the table in editing mode, the red circle for delete shows up on the left side of the table entry and tapping it shows the delete button. If I simply swipe to the left, the cell shifts left and if I tap where the delete button should be, the delete operation is triggered. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't reload the table just for one row deletion. Just delete the one row from the table.

Comment: As I mentioned, I _have_ implemented this method, but it seems not to be related to my issue. It it called (and works fine) when the (missing) delete button gets tapped.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more in that direction @maddy mentioned, I found the issue.

Since I want to add/remove one last row in the list to enter new data in "normal" mode, but not in "edit" mode, I'm overriding *func setEditing* and calling *tableView.reloadData()* there.

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    tableView.reloadData() // Recall numberOfRowsInSection to show/hide the "new cell"
}
```

So I now have to find out, how to manually trigger the calculation of row numbers and that's it.